# Callback function event listener

Tags: javascript, callback, arrow-functions

Passing callback function into event listener. Passed with arrow function vs passing without. Not able to understand why the arrow function equivalent does not work.

Could someone explain why these two snippets of code behave differently. My understanding is that both of them would execute the passed callbackfunction and then execute the code inside that function. Yet when I run the first one it behaves correctly and the second one does not. What is the difference?

```
getImageBtn.addEventListener("click", getMatchingCatsArray);
```

```
getImageBtn.addEventListener("click", getMatchingCatsArray => {
    
});
```

Comment: It's likely not working because you are setting the name of the `event` input as the name of your original function that handles the event which causes a name clash.

Comment: How is `getMatchingCatsArray` defined in the first snippet? Do you understand what `getMatchingCatsArray` is in the second snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first it seems you are correctly passing a callback function *as a callback function* to the event listener where in the second you are passing an anonymous arrow function that takes a single argument, named `getMatchingCatsArray` in your case.

In other words, the second version is like the following:

```
getImageBtn.addEventListener("click", (argOrEvent) => { ... });
```

They are not equivalent. The second version doesn't reference your `getMatchingCatsArray` callback function.